# Wrong path for wwwroot after upgrade to .NET 6

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

Have upgraded a web app from .NET 5 to .NET 6, but after the deploying to Azure the folder `wwwroot` is not found. The exception shows a path for my developing folder. In .NET 5 this was handled dynamically, and the current folder was used. I have now tried all variation I can find a think of without result so now it is time for the question: What am I missing and how to fix it?

**Exception**

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: C:\vsts\rs_source\Lakemedelshantering\LakemedelshanteringApi\LakemedelshanteringApi\wwwroot\
>
> at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsLoader.<>c.<UseStaticWebAssetsCore>b__1_0(String contentRoot)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticWebAssets.ManifestStaticWebAssetFileProvider..ctor(StaticWebAssetManifest manifest, Func`2 fileProviderFactory)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssetsCore(IWebHostEnvironment environment, Stream manifest)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost.<>c.<ConfigureWebDefaults>b__9_0(WebHostBuilderContext ctx, IConfigurationBuilder cb)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<ConfigureAppConfiguration>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IConfigurationBuilder builder)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
> at LakemedelshanteringApi.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\vsts\rs_source\Lakemedelshantering\LakemedelshanteringApi\LakemedelshanteringApi\Program.cs:line 17

**program.cs**

```
public static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();         
}  
  
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>             
{   
    webBuilder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>   
        {   
            config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());  
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables(); 
            config.Build();
        });  
       webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();   
   });
}
```

Comment: Please check: [Change the content root, app name, and environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-7.0#ccr). It is part of [Code samples migrated to the new minimal hosting model in ASP.NET Core 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that .net 6 is creating a new file ".staticwebassets.runtime.json" that handled things in Visual Studio. This file got copied to Azure which wasn't good. A good answer can be found here:

[IIS ASP.NET 6 startup throws System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: D:\agent\_work\38\s\IdentityServer\wwwroot\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71055418/iis-asp-net-6-startup-throws-system-io-directorynotfoundexception-d-agent-wor)

Regards
Carl-Johan